# Simplicial manifold associated to Lie groupoid

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff, lie-groupoids

Let $\Gamma=(\Gamma_1\rightrightarrows \Gamma_0), \Gamma’=(\Gamma’_1\rightrightarrows \Gamma’_0)$ be Lie groupoids and $\Gamma_{\bullet} ,\Gamma’_{\bullet}$ be the [simplicial manifolds associated to](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0401420v3.pdf) $\Gamma,\Gamma’$ respectively.

Question : If the simplicial manifolds $\Gamma_{\bullet}$ and $\Gamma’_{\bullet}$ are isomorphic, then, does it imply that $\Gamma=(\Gamma_1\rightrightarrows \Gamma_0)$ and $ \Gamma’=(\Gamma’_1\rightrightarrows \Gamma’_0)$ are Morita equivalent?

Has this been mentioned anywhere?

Comment: For simplicial manifold associated to Lie groupoids, please see page number 6 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0401420v3.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the simplicial manifolds are isomorphic, then the groupoids are also isomorphic, since the nerve functor from groupoid objects in a category to simplicial objects in the same category is fully faithful.

So to answer your question: yes, but in a boring way.

Comment: I did not knew about this.... nerve functor from “groupoid objects” in a category to “simplicial objects” in the same category is fully faithful... ok..

Comment: Can you suggest some reference where this has been discussed..

Comment: I think it is in a monograph by Duskin, but the usual proof for small categories and simplicial sets should adapt fine. This is originally due to Grothendieck, but there must be more recent treatments; I'll have to dig around.

Comment: Is it Simplicial methods and the interpretation of “triple” cohomology  or Higher-dimensional torsors and the cohomology of topoi: the abelian theory or some other lecture notes.

Comment: I think it's _Higher-dimensional torsors and the cohomology of topoi: the abelian theory_...

Comment: Ok.. I will see and confirm page number. Thanks .

Comment: However, it's not difficult to prove that every simplicial map comes from a unique functor: there's only one thing the functor could be, and one just has to check preservation of composition, which is a short lemma. Try it yourself!

Comment: Ok. I will try it by myself..